# Where do I put a websocket chat in MVP architecture

Tags: android, mvp

I have a question regarding MVP architecture, this is not a technical question.

I need to implement a chat (like facebook back and fourth chat) in my Android app. My question is how do I fit this to MVP.

I have these (simplified) classes:

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    private final ChatFragmentPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        List<ChatMessage> chatHistory = repository.load(); //dont think fragment should actually interact with repository
        displayChatHistory(chatHistory);
    }

    private void displayChatHistory(List<ChatMessage> chatHistory) {
        //displays chat history..
    }
}

public class ChatFragmentPresenter {

    private final ChatFragment fragment;
}

public class ChatClient {
    public interface ChatClientCallback {
        void onMessageReceived();
        void onMessageSentConfirmed();
    }

    public void start(ChatClientCallback callback) {
        //starts the chat..
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        //sends chat message..
        //if successfully sent then onMessageSentConfirmed() is called
    }
}

public class ChatRepository {

    public interface LoadChatCallback {
        List<ChatMessage> onLoadChatSuccess();
        void onLoadChatFailed();
    }

    public void load(GetChatCallback callback) {
        // loads saved chat messages..
    }

    public void save(ChatMessage message) {
        //saves chat message..
    }

    public void clear() {
        //deletes all saved chat messages..
    }
}

public class ChatMessage {

    public ChatMessage(String text, Type type) {
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public final String text;

    public final Type type;

    public enum Type {FROM_OTHER, FROM_USER}
}
```

So my questions are:

Who is going to start the chat by calling `ChatClient#start(callback)`?

Who is responsible for receiving messages from `ChatClient` and sending messages to `ChatClient`?

Who is responsible for saving received chat messages to the repository?

Who is responsible for loading chat history from repository during `onResume()`?

Should the presenter do all of this? I would prefer if there was some kind of data layer that handled all retrieving / saving / getting / setting up and closing the ChatClient, and give presenter just the data in usable form

Answer (score 0):

- Who is going to start the chat by calling ChatClient#start(callback)? 
  -- it is the Application / Service  / syncadapter
- Who is responsible for receiving messages from ChatClient and sending messages to ChatClient? -- you can use application / service / syncadapter
- Who is responsible for saving received chat messages to the repository? the application can send it to the content provider (content provider provide safe mechanism to access sqlite)
- Who is responsible for loading chat history from repository during onResume()? the flow is Activity / Fragment -> Presenter -> Repository -> Data Provider